# Creating a private chain "Fatal: Failed to write genesis block: can't start clique chain without signers" never solved the error message

Tags: private-blockchain

I encountered an extraData error and an address error during the creation of the Ethereum private chain: "Fatal: Failed to write genesis block: can't start clique chain without signers", but I believe there is no problem with my extraData because it is my The newly created address, for which I have tried many times to modify the format of extradata, but have not been successful in solving this error.

Comment: Can you share the genesis.json?